# How to install Superset on a Windows machine without using Python Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, apache-superset

I want to install Apache Superset on my Windows machine. But I don't want to use any virtual environment of Python.

Comment: In your case, I would install it in a docker.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of python-3.8.10-embed-amd64.zip, you can do the job.

and here is the solution in details, https://github.com/alitrack/superset_app

### prepare job

#### download 3 files

- [python-3.8.10-embed-amd64.zip](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/python-3.8.10-embed-amd64.zip)
- [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
- [python_geohash‑0.8.5‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl](https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/w6tyco5e/python_geohash-0.8.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl)

unzip python-3.8.10-embed-amd64.zip and goto the unzip folder

#### modify `python38._ph`

```
python38.zip
.

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
import site
```

#### install pip

```bash
python ..\get-pip.py
```

#### install python_geohash

```bash
python -m pip install ..\python_geohash‑0.8.5‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

### install apache superset and pillow

```bash
pip install apache-superset pillow
pip install markdown==3.2.2
```

#### init superset

```bash
# initialize the database:
superset db upgrade

# Create an admin user
set FLASK_APP=superset 
superset create-admin

# Load some data to play with
superset load_examples

# Create default roles and permissions
superset init
```

#### run superset

```
# To start a development web server on port 8088, use -p to bind to another port
superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to install python or create virtual env. Install docker and docker-compose.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/
cd incubator-superset/contrib/docker

# prefix with SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes to load examples:
docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh

# you can run this command everytime you need to start superset now:
docker-compose up
```

Comment: This does not work.  It throws a series of errors when it goes to the 32-step build Docker container build process.